# Trouble with Python's requests module - Getting 'ConnectionError'

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm currently working on a Python project where I'm using the requests module to make API calls. However, I keep encountering a 'ConnectionError' when trying to send a request. I've checked my internet connection, and it seems to be stable.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.example.com/data'
try:
    response = requests.get(url)
    response.raise_for_status()
# Process the response data
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

I'm wondering if there's something specific I need to configure or if there's a common mistake I might be making.

Comment: do you have a vpn on your PC ?

Comment: Temporarily remove the try/except handling and just let the full exception happen.  Maybe there is more information in the exception traceback.

Answer (score -1):

```
import requests

url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/'
try:
    response = requests.get(url)
    print(response)
    response.raise_for_status()
# Process the response data
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

Comment: Change the url for examaple, url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/'
Then you will get response 200 when you print it

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**